# show job title inside category but same category dont repeat

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**The following code:**

```
$services = $this->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array('Category','Country'),
            'joins' => array(
                 array('table' => 'services_to_categories',
                    'alias' => 'ServiceCategory',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'ServiceCategory.service_id = Service.id'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'group' => 'Service.id'
        ));
        return $services;
```

**gives me this output:**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Service] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [job_title] => director 
                    )
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [category] => Accounting & Financial
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [category] => Awards & Incentives
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7
                                [category] => Data Management
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Service] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 11
                        [job_title] => d

                    )
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7
                                [category] => Data Management
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 10
                                [category] => Internet Services
                            )
                    )
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [Service] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 12 
                        [job_title] => e
                    )
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 4
                                [category] => Business Consulting
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7
                                [category] => Data Management
                            )
                    )
            )
        )
```

**I need the output to be like below:**

```
Accounting & Financial
job_title: director 

Awards & Incentives
job_title: director

Data Management
job_title: director 
job_title: d
job_title: e

Internet Services
job_title: d

Business Consulting
job_title: e
```

How does one use this array variable $services like in the above output?

Comment: Yeah, I think stackoverflow should be used to solve a specific problem, not to get others to code for you, so you should be more specific.

Comment: maybe group by `Category.id`, not `Service.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all I did was to loop through the array and make a new array with the category as the key and the job title as an array of values.  Then I just looped through my new array and spit out the key and values.

```
<?php

$category_array = array();


// LOOP THROUGH THE MAIN ARRAY AND RESTRUCTURE IT
foreach ($start_array AS $array_element) {
    foreach ($array_element['Category'] AS $category) {
        $category_array[$category['category']][] = $array_element['Service']['job_title'];
    }
}


// LOOP THROUGH OUR NEW ARRAY AND PRINT OUT THE KEY AND VALUES
foreach ($category_array AS $department => $job_title_array) {
    print $department;
    foreach ($job_title_array AS $job_title) {
        print "\njob_title: ".$job_title;
    }
    print "\n\n";
}
```

[Here is a working demo](http://ideone.com/YFFYkK)

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve this problem with a query.

What you want is something like this:

```
+------------------------+----------+
| Accounting & Financial | director |
+------------------------+----------+
| Data Management        | director |
|                        +----------+
|                        | d        |
|                        +----------+
|                        | e        |
+------------------------+----------+
```

Obviously SQL works with tables, not nested trees, so this cannot be done.

1) SQL will give you this (using `GROUP BY Service.job_title`):

```
+------------------------+----------+
| Accounting & Financial | director |
+------------------------+----------+
| Data Management        | d        |
+------------------------+----------+
| Data Management        | e        |
+------------------------+----------+
```

2) Or this (using `GROUP BY Category.category`):

```
+------------------------+----------+
| Accounting & Financial | director |
+------------------------+----------+
| Data Management        | director |
+------------------------+----------+
```

3) or this (without using `GROUP BY`):

```
+------------------------+----------+
| Accounting & Financial | director |
+------------------------+----------+
| Data Management        | director |
+------------------------+----------+
| Data Management        | d        |
+------------------------+----------+
| Data Management        | e        |
+------------------------+----------+
```

In case 1 you're losing data: `Data Management | director` is no longer in the result.

In case 2 you're also losing data: `Data Management | d` and `Data Management | e` are no longer in the result.

So you'll have to go with case 3. Then manually (in code) transform this result into the nested array you want.

PS: These are pseudo results. The actual results will depend on a variety of factors concerning your database.